# Facade Pattern for an external API call

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I am looking at a project that has 3 classes, each with about 15 methods responsible for a variety of operations to get data from an API and return a List, or save data, or some other functionality. One class is a customer class, another is a sales class, etc.

The static methods in all of these classes are a little complex and require some setup that I'd like to streamline. I'd like to start by making things easier for the developers and make a facade that could reduce the complexity and perform some of the initial setup.

In a case where I want to reduce complexity of multiple "service" classes, is it generally acceptable/common to create multiple facades? Or just wrap them into one?

My initial reaction is to make multiple facades since it's more intuitive to the developer, for example "CustomerServiceFacade" or "CustomerService", and then another for SalesService (SalesServiceFacade). Not sure if anyone has recommendations on naming conventions.

Thanks!

Comment: Facade is supposed to make it easy for external caller to consume your service, such as it/caller does not need to know that your service will call 10 other services or classes to do a job. Naming convention is really up to the team standard and convention. I prefer to have Facade at the end to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was thinking. Would you say multiple facades is OK, as opposed to one giant one?

Comment: You should group the facades by major areas of services. For example, the customerservice and sales seem to be distinctly different areas, I'd go with different facades. Please bear in mind, I am speaking without business domain knowledge.